# bookcase design wiith css3

Tags: css

I want to create a bookcase like this [image: bookcase]

I've done some bit and the code is as follows

HTML

```
enter code here
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bookshelf.css" />
</head>

<body>

<div id="bookshelf">
   <div class="shelf">
    <div class="column" style="border-top:8px solid #444;">
     <div class="rand">
      <div class="inside"></div>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
     <div class="rand">
      <div class="rand-border"></div>
      <div class="inside"></div></div>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
     <div class="rand">
      <div class="inside"></div>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
     <div class="rand">
      <div class="inside"></div></div>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
     <div class="rand">
      <div class="inside"></div></div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div> 

</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
.shelf {
    width:360px;
    margin: 50px auto;
    box-shadow:5px 5px 50px #000;
}

.shelf .column {
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:0 10px 8px 8px;
    border-color:#444 #444 #444 #444;

}

.shelf .column .rand {

border-bottom:100px solid #888;
    border-right:1px solid #555;
}

.shelf .column .inside {
    border-style:solid;
    border-color:#000 #222 #666 #111;
    height:100px;
    background:url(wood.jpg) repeat;
    box-shadow:inset 5px 5px 20px #000, inset 2px -2px 20px #111;
}
```

Problem: I want the book holder i.e. he base of each rack as shown in the image. Would love to have some ideas about this. currently my bookcase looks like the image below.

[!bookcase screenshot](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B1GmXe1lRc7CTWthQWZ1WkhtbmM/edit)

Comment: You should just be able to add some divs and `skew` them to get that 3d effect.

Comment: Can you create a fiddle and we maybe able to see what you'v got there

Comment: [fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/ga6ud/)